# How to extract vertices from a DirectX 12 game

Tags: directx-12

I'm trying to extract geometry from a DirectX 12 game "Forza Horizon 4 Demo", and I'm having trouble with getting the vertices. For the particular DrawIndexedInstance call I am interested in, it followed a IASetVertexBuffers call that has a pViews[0].BufferLocation GPU location that does not match any ID3D12Resource's GetGPUVirtualAddress's I have looked at.

I get resources after CreateCommittedResource, CopyBufferRegion and unmap. If the BufferLocation was not an exact resource gpu location, I also tried finding the closest resource and assuming an offset to get to the BufferLocation, but I didn't find a resource with enough space for the offset. Another strange thing is that the pViews[0].StrideInBytes is only 8 bytes, which seems a bit small if a vertex needs to store position xyz and texture uv at the minimum (probably also expect a normal).

I managed to extract vertices fine from Quake3 ioq3-renderer-bgfx DirectX 12, it focused on using CopyBufferRegion to populate vertices (and it was easier since I had the source code to learn from). I also looked at renderdoc but it doesn't seem to support UWP applications (Forza Horizon 4 Demo is UWP). UWP makes things a lot harder, but I solved all the UWP problems and am just stuck on the vertex buffer.

I am just asking for ideas of things to try next to extract vertices from that IASetVertexBuffers call.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Its a little hard to share code since there is so much.
The next thing I've been trying is modifying renderdoc to support Forza Horizon 4 Demo. I'm managed to make the inject dll bit work, but am having trouble with the networking code. Just now I've got outgoing connections working but no incoming ones (probably another UWP restriction). If I ever get renderdoc working maybe I can share its code on github, it would be nice to get the official version working with UWP apps.

Comment: For renderdoc, I managed to find a way to get networking working but not completely reliable. I also have another way to trigger captures that does not need networking that is fairly reliable. My next problem is the capture procedure runs out of memory so I can't capture what I want. If anyone has any idea on how to reduce memory usage it would be appreciated. I figure if I can stop it capturing textures maybe that would help.